# Can't add images from CSS when developing custom Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem when trying to add background image to page from CSS.

Here's one example of how I'm trying to do that:

```
background: url("/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/assets/img/tile.jpg") top left repeat;
```

But all I get is whitespace.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: background: url("assets/img/tile.jpg") top left repeat;

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full URL including domain name first. The remove the domain once it works I find often the path is different from what I assume.